# Can Talend generate Scala code for Apache Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, talend, talend-mdm

I am new to Talend ETL tool. I want to use Talend to generate Spark batch jobs.

Can Talend generate Scala code instead of Java or is there a way to plug in Scala based batch job in to Talend?

Comment: Answer to your liking?

Answer (score 0):

No, it generates Java *only*.

That should not matter if using Talend as a graphic ETL-tool at a higher abstraction level though.

Comment: Would generating the code in java compared to scala make the processing slower or is it bare minimum or unnoticeable difference?